# How can i use regular expression to extract specific word without lookahead on Terraform

Tags: regex, terraform

I need  help using regular Expression on Terraform

I usually use lookahead when I want to extract word that is between word to word.

For example. If want to get "DB" from "JMJ-TEMP-DB-SUB-C" or "JMJ-TEMP-DB-SUB-A", I use the regular expression as "[A-Z]+(?=-SUB)"

However, Terraform doesn't support lookahead..

I got an error Invalid function argument as "invalid regexp pattern: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax in (?=."

Please help me with how I can get a word between TEMP and SUB in "JMJ-TEMP-{word}-SUB-C"

If you don't understand my question, aks more please.
I will explain in more detail.

Comment: Maybe `replace(local.input, "/.*-([A-Z]+)-SUB.*/", "$1")`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regex:

```
TEMP-([A-Z]+)-SUB
```

And extract the capture group.

Here is a [working example](https://regex101.com/r/uBT5EO/2) of the regex.

Comment: Thank you answer.
but your reply got a error too.. I'm sorry
The error is Inappropriate value for attribute "tags": element "Logic": string required.